# Database of cities with coordinates and timezone

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm looking for a database containing city name, location coordinates, and timezone. I thought this would be simple to find, but it has proven difficult.

(I don't see this question covered elsewhere on the site. Perhaps because it's just too basic. Also, I probably need tagging help.)

Comment: Thread from [2011+](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7155918/2327328) and from [2013+](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/2327328)

Comment: @philshem So I was just on the wrong site. . . Do those questions deserve to be migrated here, am I off topic, or neither? Just wondering.

Comment: You're at the right site, which didn't exist then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) database gives you both the geo-coordinates and the timezone for each city with a population greater than 1k.

[Here's a version of that DB with a direct access to an API and a map](http://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/geonames-all-cities-with-a-population-1000%40public/table/?disjunctive.country) on OpenDataSoft (disclaimer: I work for OpenDataSoft).

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

ESRI has their Open data on their website that might be useful for you. Check that out.

http://opendata.arcgis.com/

Answer (score 0):

I found this today that might be helpful.
https://github.com/fulvio999/world_city_location_times/tree/master